# Calling Macro in another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro situation that's a little complex, so I'll do my best to lay it out. It involves interactions between 3 different workbook files:

- the first containing generic data analysis and formatting macros
- the second containing parameters, formatting information, and more specific macros to analyze that kind of data
- the third file containing the actual data itself that is to be formatted

The workflow I envision goes like this: The generic sheet is loaded up, and a data and parameter file are selected, and the generic macros are run to apply some basic formatting. Then, a public macro with a specific name and arg list (ex. `Sub SpecialFormatting(wbk As Workbook)`) is to be run from the parameter file to do more specific formatting on the data file that's not part of the generic sheet.

How would I specify which workbook to run the macro from? I think I read somewhere about `Application.Run`, but I think that can only pass args `ByVal`. I'd need to pass a Workbook `ByRef` to be able to edit it.

I suppose for this specific situation I could pass a String with the name of the data book, but is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

Not the biggest fan of Excel and VB, being forced to work with it in the past. I've had to do my fair share of writing Excel macros to automate stuff i had no interest performing manually. I figured this out not too long ago for exporting workbooks to separate files:

```
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

wrkshtYear = Mid(wbSource.FullName, Len(wbSource.FullName) - 7, 4)

For Each sht In wbSource.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Totals" Then
        newFileName = Replace((strSavePath & "\" & UserNameWindows() & sht.Name & wrkshtYear), " ", "")
        If isFileExist(newFileName & ".xlsx") = False Then
            sht.Copy
            Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
            wbDest.SaveAs newFileName
            wbDest.Close 'Remove this if you don't want each book closed after saving.
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Maybe this will help get you started. Goodluck!